# Minimal polynom of an element

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

If for example i take an extension $E/K$ over a field $K$ and an element $\alpha \in E - K $ and I find a polynomial $P$ such that $P(\alpha)=0$.
How can I show this polynomial is the minimal polynomial?
Is it enough if I show this polynomial is irreducible over $K$ or if I show that $deg(P)=[K(\alpha ): K]$ ?
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: if $\alpha$ is a root of $P(x)\in K[x]$, then $P(x)$ is a minimal poynomial of $\alpha$ if and only if $P(x)$ is irreducible in $K[x]$. And then $\deg P(x)=\bigl[K(\alpha):K\bigr]$.

Comment: but for example if I have $\deg P(x)=\bigl[K(\alpha):K\bigr]$ do I still have the result ? (I mean if it is  hard to show that P is irreductible)

Comment: @Pierre21 Yes: if $\deg P(x)=[K(\alpha):K]$ and $\alpha$ is a root of $P(x)$, then $P(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Comment: OK, thanks ! Have a good day !